# PhoneGap desktop server is running, but cannot access on other devices or computers

Tags: ios, macos, phonegap-desktop-app

Need some help here before I pull my hair out. I just installed the latest desktop app and mobile app today. I have the PhoneGap desktop app running on OSX and the server is started on port 3000. It works fine. If I go to `192.168.0.5:3000` I get the "Hello World" app. If I go to `127.0.0.1:3000` I get the "Hello World" app. Doing a port scan says that port 3000 is open. On my iPhone 6, using the PhoneGap app it tries connecting, but eventually gives an error. In Safari I try going to `192.168.0.5:3000` and it just eventually says "Safari could not open the page..."

I have Little Snitch running, but the network filter is turned off. The OSX firewall is not running. The firewall on my router is off. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Are your computer and iPhone connected to the same network?

Comment: Yep, they are all on my home wifi connection.

Comment: Also I forgot to say, doing a port scan on my iPhone says that 3000 is not open.

Comment: If you're iPhone can't access port 3000, then it will definitely not be able to receive your app from the Desktop server since it uses port 3000.

You should ensure that port 3000 is open on your network, computer and mobile device.

Comment: Try going into Airplane mode, but turn on WiFi.

Comment: @TomSwift that worked! Thanks! Can you put that in an answer so I can mark it solved?

Comment: @Gavin done!  Glad it worked out.

Comment: @TomSwift Sorry, I saw the "+100" under your answer and figured that meant it was awarded already. Didn't realize I had to click on it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going into Airplane mode, but turn on WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Well after reading this i am sure something is not write with your network though you have turn off your firewall. to make sure this firewall is blocking try to test with https://ngrok.com/ tool

Here is the guide for you can use it 
https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

ngrok http 3000

then try it on your phone. If every thing goes write then just enable firewall and rule for your port.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a useful tool.